# Sort items like another by text

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, text, element

I have no idea, try to find easy way to sort items in 2 parents be like another. *I am so bad about sorting function*

**HTML :**

```
<div class="a">
    <h2>A :</h2>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</div>

<div class="b">
    <h2>B :</h2>
    <span>#5</span>
    <span>#One</span>
    <span>#Ipsum</span>
    <span>#4</span>
    <span>#2</span>
</div>
```

`.b` will sort same as `.a`

**To this :**

```
<div class="b">
    <h2>B :</h2>
    <span>#One</span>
    <span>#2</span>
    <span>#Ipsum</span>
    <span>#4</span>
    <span>#5</span>
</div>
```

**This is my jQuery i go so far :**

```
var $a_items = $('.a li');
var $b_items = $('.b span')

for(var i = 0; i < $a_items.length; i++){
    var $a_item = $($a_items[i]);
    var $a_text = $a_item.text();

    var $b_target = $b_items.filter(function(){return $(this).text()=='#'+$a_text;});

}
```

**Live demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/nu6zts1y/

I am looking for good performance also (Native JS can be use)

---

**Updated :** So sorry, text will be text, not only number

Comment: i think its better to create another container(.b) from .a. iff it will not going to change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You can use [**Array.prototype.sort()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and manually map/check string numbers

```js
var map = {
  '#One': 1,
  '#Two': 2,
  '#Three': 3,
  '#Four': 4,
  '#Five': 5
};
$('.b').append($($('.b span').get().sort(function(a, b) {
  var aInt = !parseInt(a.textContent.replace('#', '')) ? map[a.textContent] : a.textContent.replace('#', '');
  var bInt = !parseInt(b.textContent.replace('#', '')) ? map[b.textContent] : b.textContent.replace('#', '');

  if (aInt < bInt) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (aInt > bInt) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
})));
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
li,
span {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
.junk {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <h2>A :</h2>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</div>

<div class="b">
  <h2>B :</h2>
  <span>#5</span>
  <span>#One</span>
  <span>#3</span>
  <span>#4</span>
  <span>#2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated, not just ìnt`, sorry about that

Comment: Sorry again , just by matching "one" = "1" please

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.b').find('span').sort(function (a, b) {
   return parseInt($(a).html().replace('#',''),10) -parseInt($(b).html().replace('#',''),10) 
}).appendTo('.b');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gp0qvxLd/)**

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, about not just int :(